# Setting Maximum Size For ObjectContent Web API Preview 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wcf-web-api

When I use the the ObjectContent object to create the HttpContent to send a request via HttpClient to a Web API service I am getting the following error:

Cannot write more bytes to the buffer than the configured maximum buffer size: 65536

The following code is being used to send the request.  The Card object has about 15 properties.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var content = new ObjectContent<IEnumerable<Card>>(cards, "application/xml");
MessageBox.Show(content.ReadAsString());  //This line gives me the same error.

var response = client.Post("http://localhost:9767/api/cards", content);
```

How do I change the configured size to something greater than 65,536?

Answer (score 2):

Since the problem resides in the ReadAsString extension method I would suggest that you create your own extension method to solve the maximum buffer size issue.

Here’s an example of a ReadAsLargeString extension method that maybe solves the problem.

```
public static string ReadAsLargeString(this HttpContent content)
{
    var bufferedContent = new MemoryStream();
    content.CopyTo(bufferedContent);

    if (bufferedContent.Length == 0)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    Encoding encoding = DefaultStringEncoding;
    if ((content.Headers.ContentType != null) && (content.Headers.ContentType.CharSet != null))
    {
        encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(content.Headers.ContentType.CharSet);
    }

    return encoding.GetString(bufferedContent.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)bufferedContent.Length);
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this helps.  How would I "tell" the HttpClient to use this method?

Comment: When you have implemented the extension method try with content.ReadAsLargeString()

Comment: The post method of HttpClient accepts an HttpContent reference pointer, not a string.

Comment: My apology for not reading the question thorough enough. Have you tried?

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { MaxRequestContentBufferSize = int.MaxValue });
client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = int.MaxValue;

Answer (score 1):

There is a [thread](http://wcf.codeplex.com/discussions/242523) about this.  Try using HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead:

```
var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost:9767/api/cards");
message.Content = content; 
var client = new HttpClient();
client.Send(message, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
```

Comment: If I add MessageBox.Show(content.ReadAsString()); immediately following the var content = ... line it gives me the same error.

Comment: I updated the answer. You may need to look at the source to see why its doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the client:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient("http://localhost:52046/");

// enable support for content up to 10 MB size
HttpClientChannel channel = new HttpClientChannel() {
    MaxRequestContentBufferSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10 
};

client.Channel = channel;
```

On the Server (snippet is based preview 4 but you should get the clue):

```
public class CustomServiceHostFactory : HttpConfigurableServiceHostFactory {
    public override ServiceHostBase CreateServiceHost(string constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) {
        var host = base.CreateServiceHost(constructorString, baseAddresses);

        foreach (HttpEndpoint endpoint in host.Description.Endpoints) {
            endpoint.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;
            endpoint.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10;
        }

        return host;
    }
}
```